# Issue with margins bootrstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I have a problem regarding the margin on the right hand side of the search button not being equal to the margin on the left hand side of the select button. If I scale the search button to have the same margin on the right hand side as the select button has on the left, for a medium screen, when I enlarge the screen the margins mess up and become disproportionate and vice versa.

Here is a link to the website: https://jsfiddle.net/wvkonuxr/embedded/result/

Here is a link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/wvkonuxr/

```
<div class="search"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="searchbox">




                    <form role"form">

                        <div class="row inside">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select id="group1" name="group1" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" selected disabled> Please Select Group1 </option>
                                <option> 1 </option>
                                <option> 2 </option>
                                <option> 3 </option>
                                <option> 4 </option>
                                <option> 5 </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select id="group2" name="group2" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" selected disabled> Please Select Group2 </option>
                                <option> 1 </option>
                                <option> 2 </option>
                                <option> 3 </option>
                                <option> 4 </option>
                                <option> 5 </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Group3">
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary boxing "> Search </button>
                    </div>


                    </div>


                    </form>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: As in.. You want to center the search button?

Comment: If you increase the screen size and the searchbox changes to inline, I want the search button to be the same distance form the black background on the right and Group1 is from the black background on the left. If you play with the size of the web browser I think you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: Man. I think you need to sort the rest of your code properly first. Quite a few other problems which will have a knock on effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button needs to fill the available space of the column (col-md-1) for your grid spacing to look proper. The below methods will make the button fill the entire width of the parent (col-md-1) so that they spacing between all elements is consistent.

You can achieve this multiple ways:

**add class:**

```
.btn-full-width { width: 100%; }

<button class="btn btn-default btn-primary boxing btn-full-width" type="submit"> Search </button>
```

**add inline style:**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-primary boxing " style="width: 100%;" type="submit"> Search </button>
```

[JSFiddle Demo (add class solution)](https://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/wvkonuxr/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: Thank so much for you reply that's exactly what I wanted! Is it by any chance possible to also center the text search inside the button when it is at the medium screen setting? Thanks Again!

Comment: It doesn't change anything, the word search is centered for both the small and large screen but not the medium. Let me try to add an image to the question, so I can show you what I mean.

Comment: Yeah I did that as a solution, the only problem being is that once the user selects what they wanted from the select menu, it was not wide enough to show the the complete option selected, I did not like how that looked so I was trying to find a way to keep the col-md-4, and col-md-3 and style the button so that I wouldn't have to sacrifice the display size of the select and input menus. Is there a way for me manually style the box so it's just a tad bit bigger such that I can center the word within the button?

Comment: That's a GREAT IDEA! Thank you so much! I'm still new at this so I'm still learning the limits of front end design. Cheers JRULLE!

Answer (score 0):

Use margin :5px auto; for search button for show equal margin from left and right side of search button.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? because when I do, my search button gets stuck to the side.